# Using binding with UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working with ui-router and have several states defined. On one of my views I have a form where a user can add a 'team' to the view. I have a button for each team to view additional details on that team. What I am trying to do is set it up so that when I click on that button the team view comes up with the URL like `/#/teams/yankees` for example.

I may just not be looking in the right places or know the exact term for this, but I have not been able to figure it out so far.

Below is a snippet of what I currently have in my app.js for this portion.

```
app.config(
    ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    .state('teams', {
        url: '/teams',
        templateUrl: './templates/main/teams.html',
        controller: 'teamsCtrl'
    })
    .state('teams/{{ team.title }}', {
        url: '/teams/{{ team.title }}',
        templateUrl: './templates/main/team.html',
        controller: 'topicCtrl'
    })
```

Whenever I click on the button now to go to `/#/teams/yankees` I end up being routed by `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');` Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what your links look like... are you using ui-sref?  Typically url attributes look more like this like this:

```
.state('teams/{{ team.title }}', {
    url: '/teams/:title',
    templateUrl: './templates/main/team.html',
    controller: 'topicCtrl'
})
```

rather than the `{{}}`

Comment: That was actually it! I can't believe it was that simple of a change. Well done sir!

Comment: glad to be of service :)